# Codeigniter Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Function in model file:

```
function get_user_by_email($email)
{
    //$this->consumer->where('email=', strtolower($email));
    //$query = $this->consumer->get($this->table_name); 

    $query = $this->db->query('CALL get_user_by_email("'.strtolower($email).'")');
    echo $query->num_rows();
}
```

This function returns error `Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object in` whereas the other functions in the same file returns the row count. Also tried the active record query. But the query also returns the same error.

I tried using `result(), result_array()` also. But everything gives me error.

Thanks

Comment: Start with `var_dump($query)`

Comment: If you do the var_dump you will find that $query is a boolean. L:ooks like your query syntax is bad to me.

Comment: I tried var_dump($query). It returns bool(false). Since i don't want to use direct query i have used store procedure. When i print the query it gives me correct result.

Comment: Did I not just predict that?

Comment: `query()` is returning a bool because the called procedure failed. Maybe the procedure is not defined correctly? Please share the stored procedure code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `$this->db->reconnect();` to reconnect to the database before calling the store procedure. This resolved the issue

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$email = strtolower($email);    
$query = $this->db->query("CALL get_user_by_email('$email')");
if(is_object($query)){
    echo $query->num_rows();
}else{
    echo "Query Failed";
}
```

You might need to enclose `$email` in braces to be certain it evaluates.

```
$query = $this->db->query("CALL get_user_by_email('{$email}')");
```

Comment: Are you using mySQL or some other database? If using mySQL, what driver are you using. I believe you must use `mysqli` for called procedures to work.